# Better method rather than setTimeout for mute command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I have a Discord bot that does moderation and stuff. So I have timed the mute command and it removes the mute from the user when time ends. So I use setTimeout to query about the data from the database every second and if it finds that the expiry time is equal or is less than the current time it removes the mute. So is there any better option to do this? I am thinking this is increasing my bot's ram usage.

Comment: Maybe [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) may help

Comment: Why not use `setTimeout()` to run an unmute function once the mute duration ends. That's the kind of behavior it's meant for

Comment: @Elitezen it's not very great idea tho, because if you restart bot before this duration ends - bot won't unmute a person who got muted

Comment: Anything is an improvement over comparing times every second, just pointing out the main purpose for setTimeout

Comment: you could set a cron timer, or even save the time to unmute in a file, and set a cron timer on bot startup (to still "remember" to unmute the user after a restart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a database for this. Let's get to the solution.

## Solution

---

- Store the info in the database

  - When someone gets muted, store their data
  - You'll need to store their ID and the timestamp when the mute ends
- Check the database every certain amount of time.

  - *This can be achieved using [setInterval()](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#setintervalcallback-delay-args)*
  - Make some logic

    - Check if the mute has ended or not
    - If yes, remove the role. Otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: I am doing that only thnx though